# Put Image Into HTML Canvas (Fit Width and Height)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this HTML code :

```
<div>
    <canvas id="canvas">
    </canvas>
    <img id="canvasimg" src="{{ $photo }}" style="display:none;"/>
</div>
```

and I have this javascript to draw an image into that HTML Canvas :

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var deviceWidth = window.innerWidth;;

    canvasWidth = deviceWidth - 40;
    canvasHeight = deviceWidth - 40;

    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;

    var img = document.getElementById('canvasimg');

    imgx = 0;
    imgy = 0;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, imgx, imgy); 
</script>
```

the problem is when I load this page into wide screen, it also produce a wider canvas. while the image has fix width and height.

how to stratch that image so that it will fill the canvas perfectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `dWidth` and `dHeight` arguments for the `drawImage` function [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage).

```
ctx.drawImage(img, imgx, imgy, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: But disproportionally stretching the image will probably distort it. Perhaps you could make your solution better by scaling the image proportionally ;-)

Comment: @markE Yes, this will scale the image to whatever dimensions the canvas is.  That's how I interpreted the question.  If you want it to "fill the canvas perfectly" when they aren't the same aspect ratio, then either you have to scale the image or crop it.

Comment: I would suggest scaling the image so it fits within the fixed canvas size and then centering it. That way you wouldn't have to lose any of the image by cropping it. Here's a method to determine the scaling factor which will resize the image as large as possible to both fit in the canvas and preserve its aspect ratio: `Math.min((canvasW/imgW),(canvasH/imgH))`.

Comment: @JosiahKeller, No need for a second post...your answer nicely does the requested job -- Upvote. :-)  Here's what I was thinking: https://jsfiddle.net/yvyz2r58/. Cheers!